# How to open a pinned tab in chrome using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome

I want to open an url in a pinned tab in Chrome using Python.

**Solutions I tried**

- using `webbrowser` I cannot pin automatically the tab:

```
import webbrowser

url = "http://docs.python.org/"
# Linux
chrome_path = "/usr/bin/google-chrome %s"
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

- the `--pinned-tab-count` option seems to have been removed from the `google-chrome` CLI like this [post suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/518603/always-open-urls-from-a-pinned-tab-in-a-new-window)

Any idea on how to do it ?